# Proof of the linearity of expectation

Tags: probability, expectation

The proof of the linearity of expectation given in my textbook is:

$E[aX+b] \\= \sum_{x|p(x)>0} (ax+b)\;p(x) \\= a\sum_{x|p(x)>0}xp(x) + b \sum_{x|p(x)>0}p(x) \\= aE[X] + b$

I don't understand though why it is $\sum_{x|p(x)>0} (ax+b)\;p(x)$ instead of $\sum_{x|p(x)>0} (ax+b)\;p(ax+b)$

Why is $p(x) = p(ax+b)$ ?

Comment: The definition of expectation is $\sum_x f(x) p(x)$. Why would you change the argument of $p$?

Comment: I believe you are thinking that it should mean "the sum of $ax+b$ times the probability that I win $ax+b$," but the give probabilities are stated in terms of $x$.  If $x$ happens, you win $ax+b$.  So it's $ax+b$ times the probability that $x$ happens.  (I don't know if this will help.)

Answer (score 1):

Expectation is integration with respect to a probability measure.  Integration is linear.  Therefore expectation is linear.